# Ubuntu installation drive selection

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my Laptop but i am stuck in drive selection. It's not showing the free spaces in the drive selector but only the drive size and 'unknown' for the used space. This is an issue as all of my drives are of same size.

I've almost 5 years of code in my this laptop and i really don't want to install ubuntu upon the wrong drive !

Please can anyone guide me how can i select the drive i want to install ubuntu upon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most fool proof way (and what i'd do) ? Unplug the drive you don't want to accidentally wipe while you're doing the install.

Also, if you ever get any 'but but...there's important data!' type feelings, it's because  your backups aren't good enough.

Comment: how can i unplug my hard drive @sirex , i've 500GB hard drive and have created one drive to install Linux Ubuntu and on one Win 8.1 is already installed and one is my main drive which i dont want to loose so how can i unplud the hard drive?

Comment: so in short i've one hard which i cant eject or unplug

Comment: er... by 'drive', do you actually mean 'partition' ?

Answer (score 0):

Drive and partition are not the same.
You have one drive, and created two partitions. One partition has a win8.1 installation, and the other was created to receive an Ubuntu installation.

Is this correct?

If so, the partition with windows installed will be the first listed, ir if represented graphically, the one farthest to the left.

If I am wrong about your drive/partition setup, please elaborate.